# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mention'

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
  banned_user = await ctx.guild.bans()
  member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

  guild = ctx.guild
  embed = discord.Embed(title="unban", description=f"{member.mention} has been Unbanned ", colour=discord.Colour.red())

  for ban_entry in banned_user:
    user = ban_entry.user

    if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
      await ctx.guild.unban(user)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.send(f"you have been unbanned from: **{guild.name}**")
    return
```

Why do I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mention'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because `Member` is just a string. It's not recognized as [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Member) and you can't use `.mention` if it's just a normal string. Instead, use the `user` from the line `user = ban_entry.user` as it's the [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.User) which you can mention.

Code:

```py
@client.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
  banned_user = await ctx.guild.bans()
  member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

  guild = ctx.guild

  for ban_entry in banned_user:
    user = ban_entry.user

    if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
      await ctx.guild.unban(user)
      embed = discord.Embed(title="unban", description=f"{user.mention} has been Unbanned ", colour=discord.Colour.red())
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.send(f"You have been unbanned from: **{guild.name}**")
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Its `member.author.mention`.

```py
@client.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
  banned_user = await ctx.guild.bans()
  member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

  guild = ctx.guild
  embed = discord.Embed(title="unban", description=f"{member.author.mention} has been Unbanned ", colour=discord.Colour.red())

  for ban_entry in banned_user:
    user = ban_entry.user

    if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
      await ctx.guild.unban(user)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.send(f"you have been unbanned from: **{guild.name}**)
    return
```